# Weekly percentage breakdowns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using two tables, one called customer and one called orders. 
In the customer table there are three customerType values, 'cash', 'corporate' and 'personal'.
I need to find the percentage of sales for each customerType for each week.

This is the mess I have so far:

```
select Customer.customerType as 'Customer Type',
    format(dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, [dbo].[Order].orderDate) % 7, [dbo].[Order].orderDate), 'dd-MM-yy') as 'Week of',
    (case 
        when Customer.customerType = 'Cash' then (select sum([dbo].[Order].totalValue) from [dbo].[Order], Customer
            where [dbo].[Order].customerId = Customer.id
            and Customer.customerType = 'Cash')
        when Customer.customerType = 'Corporate' then (select sum([dbo].[Order].totalValue) from [dbo].[Order], Customer
            where [dbo].[Order].customerId = Customer.id
            and Customer.customerType = 'Corporate')
        else (select sum([dbo].[Order].totalValue) from [dbo].[Order], Customer
            where [dbo].[Order].customerId = Customer.id
            and Customer.customerType = 'Personal')
    end) / sum([dbo].[Order].totalValue) as 'Percentage of Sales for the Week'
from [dbo].[Order], Customer
where Customer.id = [dbo].[Order].customerId
group by format(dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, [dbo].[Order].orderDate) % 7, [dbo].[Order].orderDate), 'dd-MM-yy'), Customer.customerType
order by format(dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, [dbo].[Order].orderDate) % 7, [dbo].[Order].orderDate), 'dd-MM-yy')
```

It's such a mess and I am so lost. Please help!!!

Comment: can you show your table schema, sample data and expected result ?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the query that you posted, i have simplified into following

Note :

(1) Avoid using old style join `table1, table2` use `INNER JOIN` instead. (2) use table alias

```
SELECT  c.customerType as [Customer Type],
        format(dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, o.orderDate) % 7, o.orderDate), 'dd-MM-yy') as [Week of],
        SUM (o.totalValue) 
      / SUM (SUM (o.totalValue) ) OVER (PARTITION BY format(dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, o.orderDate) % 7, o.orderDate), 'dd-MM-yy'))
            as [Percentage of Sales for the Week]
FROM    Customer c
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] o  on  c.id    = o.customerId
GROUP BY c.customerType,
         format(dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, o.orderDate) % 7, o.orderDate), 'dd-MM-yy')
ORDER BY [Week of], c.customerType
```